# PhpStorm recommended file type association for *.heex files?

Tags: elixir, phpstorm, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to figure out the best file type association for `.heex` files and I can't quite get anything set that's right for it. Does anyone have a recommended file type association or a plugin that includes a good file type association for `.heex` files?

I do already have the Elixir plugin installed and that did not include any color coding for `.heex` files and it's driving me insane.

Or, if a good file type association does not exist, what do you recommend I do to get the files' text color-coded?

Thanks!

Comment: Vote for https://github.com/KronicDeth/intellij-elixir/issues/2102, see also https://elixirforum.com/t/intellij-formatting-html-eex-files/15832/16.

Comment: PhpStorm as well as many other IDEA-based IDEs comes with **"TextMate Bundles"** bundled plugin that provides **syntax highlighting** for various languages (that are not natively supported by that IDE). Find a TextMate bundle for your language and add it at `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | TextMate Bundles` and see how it goes.